# Processing an array of functions in $q.all()

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, function, q

I have a bunch of functions that are loaded via services that need to be executed from a `$q.all([funcA(),funcB(),funcC()])`.  And then I have json file which tells the script which services to process.  The problem I have is getting the json value to be saved into an array that that can be passed to the `$q.all(doFuncs).then` where the values of the array will be processed as functions.

The functions/services, as mentioned, are loaded from an earlier global script, defined as:

```
function funcA() {
 // do something
}
function funcB() {
 // do something
}
function funcC() {
  // do something
}
```

The json file which is dynamically loaded from a remote server will allow me to turn on/off different vendors to be processed as needed:

json:

```
var vendorObj = { 
   "vendorA" : {
      "cName" : "Foo Company",
      "active" : 1,
      "funcName" : "funcA"
   },
   "vendorB" : {
      "cName" : "Bar Company",
      "active" : 0,
      "funcName" : "funcB"
   },
   "vendorC" : {
      "cName" : "FooBar Company",
      "active" : 1,
      "funcName" : "funcC"
   }
}
```

Looping through the json if "active == 1", then add the function name to an array.

```
var doFunctions = [] ;
for (var key in vendorObj) {
   if (vendorObj[key].active == 1) {
      doFunctions.push(window[vendorObj[key].funcName]) ;
   }
}
```

If I process them like in this for loop it works, the added/active functions are executed properly:
for (var x=0;xx ;
}

However, in `$q.all()` when manually defined, the functions are passed in an array as '$q.all(**[funcA(),funcC(),funcG()]**).then(function(response) { ... })'

So the problem I am having is how to pass `doFunctions` so each value is auto-recognized as a function as I am not able to add the `()` after each array value when simply just stating the array name as in the following:

```
$q.all(doFunctions).then(function(response) {
   // process `response`
}
```

Comment: You need to show the script where the functions come from.

Comment: Where are the functions defined? In what scope or context do they exist?

Comment: if the functions do not have any namespace then you can access them with window[vendorObj[key].funcName]

Comment: @Phil - can you or someone please reopen, I rewrote the whole question.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `doFunctions.push( window[vendorObj[key].funcName]() )`?

Comment: @Phil - When I do that I am getting error: `TypeError: window[vendorObj[key].funcName] is not a function`

Comment: Sounds like those functions don't exist then, at least not at the global scope. Are you sure they're included **before** this script runs?